# How can I connect to the recovery console of a remote server?

Tags: server, ssh, fsck, recovery-mode, telnet

So, my Ubuntu server's hard drive went into emergency read-only mode while I was in an SSH session. Thankfully, I was able to connect with SFTP and grabbed a few critical files, although, stupidly, it didn't occur to me at the time to download all my other projects. I then restarted the server through SSH, hoping it would automatically repair any disk errors and boot normally.

It didn't, so now I cannot connect to SSH. I'm assuming it is sitting in recovery console. Does recovery console have any emergency remote services enabled by default? Like telnet on a really high port number or something? I won't have physical access to the machine for another few months, so I don't know what to do.

I believe it is running Ubuntu Server 10.04. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't think that you can access this server without [IMPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) or a solution by the one who has acccess to the hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately the server doesn't have IPMI, but I will definitely look into it as a preventative measure for the future. Thanks.